# Angular2 - Compilation issue with nested component

Tags: angular, typescript, tsc

I have two `Angular2` components coded with `TypeScript`:

> app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles : [`
        .parent {
            background : #c7c7c7;
            color : #000;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="parent">
            <h1>{{name}}</h1>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

> app/child.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    styles : [`
        .child {
            background : #aaa;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="child">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
    name = "Child Component";
}
```

If in the component `app/app.component.ts` I don't nest the component: `app/child.components.ts` everything compiles correctly.

Please, check here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5PfPmDoUkxYRirCtwSGa?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

But if I nest it, then I think the transpiler is unable compile...

> app/app.component.ts (nesting: app/child.components.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles : [`
        .parent {
            background : #c7c7c7;
            color : #000;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <div class="parent">
            <h1>{{name}}</h1>
            <child-component></child-component>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Please, check here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qpsYQx4Ih4qQ1dyk3tFH?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

My questions are:

1- What is failing on the above code?

2- Is there a way I can check an error log of the TypeScript transpiler to see what's going on when there are transpilation issues like here?

Comment: Which version of Angular2 are you using ? There is no `directives` declaration in the component, it goes in the `NgModule`

Comment: Well, there is no `AppModule` and `main.ts` in your project!!

Comment: I really suggest you start from the beginning of the tutorial to get to know the basics :) This is actually a really good tutorial all the way through! https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: then, how do I make the nesting go through?, could you fork the code and give me one solution?. Make the changes you want (the lesser the better). About the version..., just assume is the version that plnkr uses. And yes, I'm gonna study that tutorial, thanks!

Comment: The nesting looks almost correct, but you are missing some big parts (files) from your project! You really need to start at the tutorial, where all files are introduced and explained before you can even move forward to something like nesting.

Comment: You was right, I missed some files (that I already had on my computer). I modified my code: plnkr.co/edit/… Could you say me what's the detail that is making my application fails now?, I need that detail. Maybe you can pass me a forked link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, feeling nice today ;)

You are missing two big pieces in your app. BTW, Plunker has preset Angular 2 templates, from which you can start playing around. So what you were missing was a NgModule and main.ts-file.

You can read more about NgModule [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html), but as an excerpt from that page:

> An Angular module is a class decorated with @NgModule metadata.
>
> The metadata:
>
> - declare which components, directives and pipes belong to the module.
> - make some of those classes public so that other component templates
>     can use them.
> - import other modules with the components, directives
>     and pipes needed by the components in this module.
> - provide services
>     at the application level that any application component can use.

Since you have a child component, you also need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`, since you have the `<child-component>` tag, i.e element. Here would be the NgModule that would work for you, so very minimal:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Other missing file was main.ts, which launches the application.

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Your components were almost correct. But we don't use "directives" anymore, everything is taken care of in the NgModule.

**Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tB7kIC4JPsCXTJyVsZCD?p=preview)**

As I said, I really suggest you start from the beginning of the tutorial from [Angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) The tutorial is very good in my opinion!

Comment: You was right, I missed some files (that I already had on my computer). I modified my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/qpsYQx4Ih4qQ1dyk3tFH?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts Could you say me what's the detail that is making my application fails now?, I need that detail. Maybe you can pass me a forked link.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ah5dq2o947heHj4cn9Mi?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts That is your plunker with updated index file, added config file, removed directives, and added import of child component. Keep in mind now, that DO NOT copy the config file to your local project. It's only supposed to be in plunker. And read the tutorial!!!

Comment: do you know if is there a way I can check an error log of the TypeScript transpiler to see what's going on when there are transpilation issues like before?

Comment: I would suggest you just access the developer tools in your browser. That is IMO the best way to check for errors.